# iframe sandbox not loading foreign fonts

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

So I have a web app that contains an `iFrame` that loads bootstrap [glyphicons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons)

index.html iframes frame.html

Glyphicons is basically a font of symbols that you can use instead of images. Benefit of this you can change the size without stretching and you can change the color easily.

HTML5 allows you to simply import a font as well as CSS3

example:

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';   
 src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
 src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix')
 format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') 
 format('woff2'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') 
 format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') 
 format('svg');
}
```

This works fine while the iframe src file is run on its own. However the second you load it in an `**iframe sandbox**` it then fails.

this fails

```
<iframe src="frame.html" sandbox="allow-scripts" />
```

however, this works

```
<iframe src="frame.html" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts" />
```

`allow-same-origin` is a huge security risk for me.

Is there a `white-list` or `black-list` that i can modify to allow fonts. There doesnt seem to be sandbox property that allows it.

## Any help would be appreciated

Comment: So since i couldnt find an answer my hack to get this to work is embedding the font in the CSS file. A good tool for this is http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator  expert mode

Comment: correction... it works inline in the same html file but a sister css file wont work

Answer (score 0):

Very old question, but to anyone else who comes across this, my guess is that you might have fallen afoul of CORS.

You'll want to send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` from your server, or access that font from a CDN.